# Can someone tell me what font is this?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

Could someone tell me what font is this, is from LCD Soundsystem's album This Is Happening, thanks[image]

Comment: Please follow our [font ID requirements](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2366)

Answer (score -1):

You can try using a font identifying service like [WhatTheFont](https://www.myfonts.com/pages/whatthefont) or uploading your image to [Adobe Fonts](https://fonts.adobe.com/fonts) in the search bar. It's unlikely that you'll find an *exact* match, but you should be able to find some very similar ones that would match what you're looking for.